# Cannot read property 'object3D' of undefined error, when remove() of AFrame component is explicitly called

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am writing a custom timer component for AFrame. The timer is made using basic three.js by grouping multiple three.js object3D's and finally set to the entity (el) using

```
seconds = new THREE.Object3D();
parent1 = new THREE.Object3D();
seconds.add(parent1);
parent2 = new THREE.Object3D();
seconds.add(parent2);    
this.el.setObject3D('Mesh', seconds);
```

The timer works fine. But when I call remove(), containing the following code.

```
this.el.removeObject3D('Mesh');
```

I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'object3D' of undefined. 
I logged el.object3D and the type was "Group" but seconds was "Object3D".

I need to remove the component from the scene. what can I do to fix this?
Please find the code to the component on glitch [link](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/smoggy-king) 
 Thanks.

Comment: Needs more context. A simple example to reproduce will make easier to help you. glitch.com is a good option.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos hello, you can find the code here [link](https://github.com/kewalkishang/aframe-clock-component/tree/master/timer-component)

Comment: Thanks, glitch is better so people can just run it on a single click. On github we have to clone, run local server... the easier you make it the more likely to get help.

Comment: I also recommend editting the original question and not burying the link to code in the comments

Comment: @DiegoMarcos done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

Use the DOM API to remove the entity:

```
var clock=document.getElementById("timer");
document.querySelector("a-scene").removeChild(clock);
```

Modified [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/peach-gasoline)

You can also remove the component from the entity:

```
var clock=document.getElementById("timer");
clock.removeAttribute('timer-component');
```

[glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sprinkle-tuna?path=index.html:23:49)

The remove method is not meant to be called directly but a life cycle method invoked automatically when the [component is detached](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/component.html#remove) from the entity or the entity is removed from the DOM.